# OpenShift: Too many active sessions

Tags: jsf, jboss, scalability, openshift, haproxy

I got an error in OpenShift scalable (JSF JBossAS 7.1) application:

> 2014/06/19 03:39:55,581 FATAL
>   [org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl]
>   (http-127.12.210.1-127.12.210.1-8080-2) Exception initializing page
>   context: java.lang.IllegalStateException: createSession: Too many
>   active sessions

I configured STATE_SAVING_METHOD to client but error is the same.

Why does this error appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the solution is put next code snippet to jsp page which is available for haproxy

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```